# How to modify a tabl value in a Powerpoint with Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I read an existing file into my programm an add an new slide (slide 3) with a table. On slide 2 there is also a table, an I have to change some values there.  How can I access this table, get the values to recalculate and set the new values in this table.

```
Apache POI 3.14-20160307
```

Comment: HSLF (`ppt`) or XSLF (`pptx`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this way. To check it out, I set the name of the shape in powerpoint ( klick in it and then press `STRG + F10` ). This is my solution

```
for(XSLFShape shape : slide){
        shape.getAnchor();

        if (shape instanceof XSLFTable){
            XSLFTable t = (XSLFTable) shape;

            if(t.getShapeName().equals("Table1")){
                t.getCell(1,1).clearText();
                t.getCell(1,1).addNewTextParagraph().addNewTextRun().setText("TABELE 1");
            }
          }
        }
```